# Facebook Connect: Send email to proxy address?

Tags: facebook

When users connect to my site with facebook connect i use this code to get their proxied email:

```
$user_details=$fb->api_client->users_getInfo($_SESSION['fb_uid'], array('last_name','first_name','proxied_email'));
$email = $user_details[0]['proxied_email'];
```

It works fine, i get strange-looking-emails ending with @proxymail.facebook.com.

The problem is that i can't send emails to this address. The user never receives them.

And yes i have changed the email domain in the application settings to mydomain.com

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since last month, you can ask users permission to retrieve their actual email, instead of the proxied one.
Check out this message on the facebook developers blog: http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=355

Comment: Ah okay, after reading that page and followed some links from it, it seems like you need to ask for the 'email' permission even if you just want to use the proxy address.